# How to retain one of the duplicated rows randomly in r (not the first duplicated row)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, duplicates, aggregate

I have a large dataset with many duplicated rows. I want to remove duplicated rows and retain only unique rows. But I don't want to retain the first duplicated row, which is the case in `dplyr::distinct()`. What I want is for example if there are three rows with similar answer, I want r to retain one of them randomly (not always the first duplicated row).

For example if my data frame looks like this:

```
ID<-c(1:10)
age<-c(18,18,19,19,19,20,20,20,21,21)
Answer1<-c("yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no")
Answer2<-c("yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no")

df<-data.frame(ID, age, Answer1, Answer2)
print(df)

ID age Answer1 Answer2
1  18     yes     yes
2  18     yes     yes
3  19      no      no
4  19      no      no
5  19      no      no
6  20      no      no
7  20      no      no
8  20     yes     yes
9  21      no     yes
10 21      no      no
```

Those individuals who are at the same age plus whose first and second answer match, I consider them as duplicates and I want to randomly retain one of them (and delete the rest). I tried the following `dplyr` command. The problem is the command retains the first duplicated row.

```
df.new<-df%>%
  group_by(age) %>%
  distinct(Answer1, Answer2,.keep_all = TRUE)
```

Is there a simple command to randomly retain one of the duplicated rows?

If that is not possible do you know how I can create additional column that indicate if individual is unique or duplicate (something like this)

```
   ID age Answer1 Answer2    Status
1  18     yes     yes        duplicate
2  18     yes     yes        duplicate
3  19      no      no        duplicate
4  19      no      no        duplicate
5  19      no      no        duplicate
6  20      no      no        duplicate
7  20      no      no        duplicate
8  20     yes     yes           unique
9  21      no     yes           unique
10 21      no      no           unique
```

Note that here an individual get duplicate status if there is at least one individual with similar age, Answer1 and Answer2 in the dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without worrying about the duplicates you could select one random row for each unique value of `age`, `Answer1` and `Answer2`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(age, Answer1, Answer2) %>% slice_sample(n = 1)
#With sample_n
#df %>% group_by(age, Answer1, Answer2) %>% sample_n(1)
```

If there is only 1 row in a group this will by default select that row.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[sample(seq_len(.N), 1)], .(age, Answer1, Answer2)]
```